# How to retrieve records from mysql DB based on different users role PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Am maintaining hundreds of thousands of records in MySQL table & PHP as code behind.

In our online portal, I should give access to user to view records based on their geographical criteria - Paid Membership Portal.

For Example: If user wants to see only records for India, we will provide access to view only those (that user should not see other records). If user paid & wanted India & England records, we should display only these two countries records (Not all records).

Providing Access in my Control (i.e Admin control)

Path flow: User Login--> Display only particular Records (Providing Access in my control)

How can I frame MySQL query for displaying a page?

Example User types: We have to provide access for below user criteria.

- User1: Wanted only India records.
- User2: Wanted only Australia & Japan records.
- User3: Wanted only US & UK records.
- User4: Wanted only Mexico, Russia, Japan, China records.
- User5: Wanted only South Africa, Kenya, Sri Lanka records.

My website have only 2 pages

1. Login Page
2. display Page

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: <?php dbconnect();

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: omg!! i can give you a gun, can you please kill me. Dude we are ready to analyze the code and help you. Don't behave like a child.

Comment: @PravinS 

**Display Page: **

<?php 
dbconnect();
$user_access=get_userrole(); //i will fetch user access countries from user table
mysql_query("select * from records where countryname in ($user_access)");
//display part
?>


**Table format**

Usertable: Fields- name, address, ....., access_countries
main records table: Fields: country_name, detail1, detail2, detail3.....


**For above setup how can i display records for various types of users.??**

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried already and where exactly the error is coming, and you can edit question to post your code @VigneshRogith

Comment: @PravinS      Some bug. Sorry Plz refer here http://newprojectstracker.com/images/stack_code.JPG

Comment: If you need to add code to your question, use the edit button. Do not post code in comments and do not post links to pictures of our code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to structure your data appropriately. Sounds like a fairly standard relational database. I would design it with the following tables:

1. Users (UserID as primary key)
2. Countries (CountryID as primary key)
3. UserCountries (has foreign keys to UserID and CountryID).
4. Records (has foreign key to CountryID

That way, when the user logs in, you know their UserID. You can query the UserCountries table to find which countries they have requested. Then you can query the Records table to find only records for those countries. Probably you can do this all in one query, something like this:

```
select *
from Records R
inner join UserCountries UC on UC.CountryID = R.CountryID
where UC.UserID = UserID
```